# awk regular expression not working

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to see if there are files created by users that has pattern of LX***** where *'s are all digits. I am using awk but it seems it is not right.

This is working

```
<command_to_print_files> | awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^LX[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/) print $1"\t"$4}'
```

and this is not

```
<command_to_print_files> | awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^LX[0-9]{5}$/) print $1"\t"$4}'
```

Why? How can I make it work given that I will use awk, not any other commands. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second `awk` script worked for me — on Mac OS X 10.11.4 with BSD Awk and with GNU Awk (4.1.3).  (Given `LX99999 D E F`, it printed `LX99999 F`; given `LX8888 A B C` and `LX000000 X Y Z`, it printed nothing.)  Which version of Awk are you using on which platform?  Note that if you wished, you could use `awk '$1 ~ /^LX[0-9]{5}$/ {print $1"\t"$4}'`

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.7 :( @JonathanLeffler. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I happened to have the source for GNU Awk 3.1.7 on my machine, so I compiled it and can confirm that it does not recognize the pattern that GNU Awk 4.1.3 does recognize.  If you want the notation to work, time to upgrade.

Comment: RE intervals were disabled by default until gawk 4.0 (previously you needed `--re-interval` to enable them). Get a new version of gawk as your current version is a few years out of date and you are missing a ton of extremely useful functionality (see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mac OS X awk` (`BSD awk`) should work with:

```
ls| awk '/^LX[0-9]{5}/ {print $1}'
```

or

```
<command_to_print_files> | awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^LX[0-9]{5}$/) print $1"\t"$4}'
```

But the `GNU awk` doesn't(verions >4 do support it).

To use `{}` in regex GNU awk use `--re-interval` or `--posix`.

This should work for you :

```
<command_to_print_files> | awk --re-interval '{ if ($1 ~ /^LX[0-9]{5}$/) print $1"\t"$4}'
```

or

```
ls| awk --re-interval '/^LX[0-9]{5}/ {print $1}'
```

Note(from [Ed Morton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) comment) : Use `--re-interval` rather than `--posix` as the latter disables all of the gawk extensions(e.g. gensub() )

Comment: Working. Thanks :)

Comment: Which version of GNU Awk were you using?  It worked for me with GNU Awk 4.1.3 but not with 3.1.7 — without the `--re-interval` or `--posix` options.

Comment: Use `--re-interval` rather than `--posix` as the latter disables all of the gawk extensions, e.g. `gensub()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes the new ones support `{..}`. Since most people don't update the GNU AWK they get with the OS, it remains outdated & don't support the use of curly braces in RegEx.